# Linq query to get all numbers (positive and negative) up to N that sum up to number K

Tags: c#, linq, combinations

I have a specific assignment to make a function **that only uses LINQ**, this is what makes it challenging for me.
The problem is something like:

Generate all expressions of plus and minus (+-) of N numbers that sum up to K.

Example if I have N = 3, K = 0. I should have at some point 8 combinations of numbers with plus and minus (2 to the power of n combinations), and with some Where clause I should only extract those who sum up to 0 (which is K).
So the result should be something like:

-1 -2 +3 = 0;

+1 +2 -3 = 0;

Again, I can only use LINQ queries, nothing else, and I can't wrap my head around this problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi. Can you give us some indications of the LINQ queries you have built so far to try and solve this problem? Just want to have a feel to what extent you have tried to solve this question.

Comment: If you can't figure out how to do it because the requirement of using LINQ is getting in the way, temporarily throw that requirement away and just figure out how to do in any way. Once you get it working, then start figuring out how to do it using LINQ. If you have a solution in hand, you'll have a much better grasp of the nature of the problem

Comment: Sure, I tried multiple queries up till now, and the best I could manage was this:             return Enumerable.Range(0, rows).Select(i => Enumerable.Range(1, n).Select(j => baseValues[i / (rows / (j * 2)) % 2] * j))
            .Where(s => s.Sum() == k);   Which is not good enough as there are multiple results that return the same numbers. but for very small inputs it somehow works.

Comment: @FlyDog57 Don't get me wrong, I could solve something like this using usual c# code, my problem is with LINQ, as even though I have multiple solutions in my head, for example, starting with a empty array { }, and then doubling they array with { {1}, {-1}}, then again with { {1, -2}, {1, 2},  {-1, -2}, {-1, 2}} and so on and at the end extracting the correct combinations.  But the problem is that I'm not that experienced in LINQ yet and I have a hard time to come up with a query like the solution above. This is why I ask for help, or hints or anything, because right now, I'm stuck

Comment: @AQROBY - Please do not post answers to your question in the question itself. Post them as an answer to your question. That's how this system works.

Comment: @Enigmativity Ok got it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to anyone that tried to help, unfortunately all the solutions were too complex for this problem so I managed to find my own solution, which is a little more straightforward, but your solutions guided me in the right direction.

```
IEnumerable<string> seed = new[] { "" };

var x = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Aggregate(seed, (a, _) => a.
        SelectMany(s => new[] { s + "+", s + "-" }));

return x.Select((a) => a.Select((a, b) => a == '+' ? b + 1 : (b + 1) * -1))
.Where(r => r.Sum() == k);
```

Comment: Keep in mind with this solution you're creating a boat load of strings - and that will put pressure on the GC.

Comment: I made an alternative based on your approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70148903/259769

Answer (score 4):

So the question is about deciding if each integer from 1 to N inclusive, should be added or subtracted?

```cs
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> AllCombinations(int n, int k)
    => Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << n)
        .Select(i =>
            Enumerable.Range(0, n)
                .Select(j => (i & 1 << j) == 0 ? j + 1 : -j - 1)
        )
        .Where(r => r.Sum() == k);
```

Comment: Very nice. Super fast and no unnecessary objects created.

Comment: Though the caller may enumerable the inner enumerable a second time. The cost should be fairly low, compared to the cost of finding the answers.

Comment: The fluent syntax is nice too `public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> AllCombinations(int n, int k) =>  from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << n) let r = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(j => (j + 1) * ((i & 1 << j) == 0 ? 1 : -1)) where r.Sum() == k select r;`.

Comment: Great! “ (i & 1 << j) == 0” is what I wanted to find, but couldn’t. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, this was great really, I managed to find my own solution but this was really smart

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hackish solution, using only brute force. I'm sure a most elegant one can be found. It will also fail to produce results for more than 30 numbers.

```cs
Enumerable
    .Range(0, (int)Math.Pow(2, N))
    .Select(i => Convert.ToString(~i, 2)
        .Reverse()
        .Take(N)
        .Select((c, i) => c == '1' ? i + 1 : -(i + 1))
        .ToList())
    .Where(l => l.Sum() == K)
    .ToList();
```

Some explanations:

As you pointed out, for N numbers, there are 2^N combinations of sums with + or -. So the first step is to build these 2^N combinations.

```cs
Enumerable
    .Range(0, (int)Math.Pow(2, N))
```

constructs the first 2^N numbers. Lets consider in this example that N = 10.

```cs
.Select(i => Convert.ToString(~i, 2)
```

Transforms each number to its binary string representation, but inverted (0 is replaced by 1, and 1 is replaced by 0). The purpose of the inversion is to get all the 32 digits of the number, otherwise the number 2, i.e. 10 in binary would be represented by the string "10". And we want a string as long as N. i.e. "0000000010". With that trick, instead of "01", we get "1111111111111111111111111111101".

That string is then considered as a sequence of characters.

```cs
.Reverse()
```

That sequence is reversed: "1011111111111111111111111111111",

```cs
.Take(N)
```

And we take only the first N characters: "1011111111".

```cs
.Select((c, i) => c == '1' ? i + 1 : -(i + 1))
.ToList())
```

Then we project each character to an number, which is the index + 1, with a sign depending on the character itself: if equal to '1' plus, otherwise -. Which gives: 1, -2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 in the example used until now.

```cs
.Where(l => l.Sum() == K)
.ToList();
```

From there we have constructed all possible sequences, so we can sum these and filter the ones for which the sum equals our target.

Of course you could add a check: if |K| > (N^2 + N)/2, there is no need to calculate, there won't be no matches...

As a query you try by copy/paste in Linqpad:

```cs
void Main()
{
    Utils.Calculate(10, 1)
        .Select(e => new 
        {
            Sum = e.Sum(),
            Elements = e
        })
        .Dump();
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
public static class Utils
{
    public static List<List<int>> Calculate(int N, int K)
    {
        // Enumerable.Range will throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException 
        // if N <= 0 || N > 30
        
        return Enumerable
            .Range(0, (int)Math.Pow(2, N))
            .Select(i => Convert.ToString(~i, 2)
                .Reverse()
                .Take(N)
                .Select((c, i) => c == '1' ? i + 1 : -(i + 1))
                .ToList())
            .Where(l => l.Sum() == K)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
The same logic could also be written as:

```cs
Enumerable.Range(1, (int)Math.Pow(2, N))
    .Select(i => int.MaxValue - i + 1)
    .Select(i => Convert.ToString(i, 2)
        .Skip(31-N)
        .Select((c, i) => c == '1' ? i + 1 : -(i + 1))
        .ToList())
    .Where(l => l.Sum() == K)
    .ToList()
```

To order of the lists will be different from the first method, which doesn't matter for the result.

Comment: `(int)Math.Pow(2, N)` is awful. `1 << N` is much better as it stays as an integer. Turn it into a function if you like, `Func<int, int> pow2 = n => 1 << n;`

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should have used the relation between bit shifting and power of two, forgot it. I was sure there was room for improvement, as my introduction stated. Especially concerning the string hack. You and @JeremyLakeman proved it.

Comment: Thank you so much man for your solution and your explanations, unfortunately, the code is way too complex and "hackish" as you call so it was rejected, but I've managed to find my own solution after all, I added it in the original post at the end

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly simple way:

```
int n = 3;
int k = 0;

IEnumerable<int[]> query =
    from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << n)
    let b = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(n, '0')
    let r = Enumerable.Range(1, n)
    let d = r.Zip(b, (x, y) => y == '0' ? x : -x).ToArray()
    let s = d.Sum()
    where s == k
    select d;
```

Running that gives me:

```
1, 2, -3
-1, -2, 3
```

And, for example, with `n = 9` and `k = 33` I get:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -6, 7, 8, 9
1, -2, 3, -4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
-1, 2, 3, 4, -5, 6, 7, 8, 9
-1, -2, -3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

---

This avoids creating strings:

```
IEnumerable<bool> GetBits(int q, int v) =>
    q == 0
    ? Enumerable.Empty<bool>()
    : GetBits(q - 1, v >> 1).StartWith((v & 1) == 1);

int n = 13;
int k = 75;

IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> query =
    from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << n)
    let bs = GetBits(n, i)
    let rs = Enumerable.Range(1, n)
    let ds = rs.Zip(bs, (x, y) => y ? x : -x)
    let s = ds.Sum()
    where s == k
    select ds;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to find my own solution after all but this was great, it really guided me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative, based on the OP's answer, that uses `int[]` to build up the list of candidates.

```
int n = 26;
int k = 8;

var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

IEnumerable<int[]> seed = new[] { new int[] { } };
var xss =
    Enumerable
        .Range(1, n)
        .Aggregate(
            seed,
            (a, i) => a.SelectMany(s => new[]
            {
                s.Append(i).ToArray(),
                s.Append(-i).ToArray(),
            }))
        .Where(xs => xs.Sum() == k)
        .ToArray();

sw.Stop();
sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump();
```

This is faster than the OP's string building method.